# The most secure external hard drives on the market

Tags: hardware

Wondering what the most secure hard drives are on the market, as stuff like [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/133832/securing-external-drives) points out that sometime the "encryption software" that comes bundled with external hard drives is probably insecure and it would be better to use something open source where you can check the code. Also I have just read here and there that this and that has this or that security flaw at the hardware level. Wondering if this is the case everywhere (obviously there are probably going to be unknowns at the hardware level), that all the external drives have one flaw or another, or if there are some drives out there with a good reputation for security. Trying to get a sense if it is worthwhile considering what drive you get or if it is pretty much pointless as all of them are insecure in one way or another. If it's purely opinion based well then I will assume that they are all insecure in one way or another lol, but hopefully there's one or two that are better than the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardware encryption meeting the standards for FIPS 140-2 certification is [validated](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Cryptographic-Module-Validation-Program/Standards) by the National Institute of Standards and Technology (US Dept of Commerce).

These devices conform to some of the highest standards for physical and Cryptographic security. Reliance on purely a vendors trust is not needed if you verify the product is listed with NIST as validated.

One of the most common FIPS 140-2 devices used in industry is the Ironkey and has been arround for many years.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no drive with open hardware and firmware, it depends on your trust for the vendor.

Research shows most of them have flaws if someone just looks closely. The sane thing is to just use any drive and encrypt your data using open-source software and don't trust any hardware encryption.

Comment: Wondering if there are any highly trusted vendors, of if it's just a personal thing.

Comment: In my opinion there are none, but this is just a personal thing.